# Update Action Bar Menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm turning invisible my refresh button in the action bar (sherlock action bar). But, I don't know how to call the actionbar update (`onPrepareOptionsMenu()` or `InvalidateOptionsMenu()`) inside my `makeupdate()` function (I need this call inside the function). I've been search in stackoverflow and google for hours... tested all and get nothing...

My `makeupdate()` function:

```
public void makeupdate(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh);
    item.setVisible(false);
}
```

**EDIT - My Code**

```
public class SiteActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    final Activity MyActivity = this;
    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionbar;
    private Menu mainMenu;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 


        actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionbar.setTitle("APP");
        actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.site);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");  
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/noconnection.html");

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            }
        });

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new SiteActivityClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/noconnection.html");
            }   
        });                 
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void makeupdateshowToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainMenu.findItem(R.id.refresh).setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, menu);
        mainMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Comment: is makeupdate a method of your activity?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a `addJavascriptInterface` so the function is called by the javascript in my webview - This activity is a webview based activity.

Comment: Did you extend SherlockActivity / SherlockFragmentActivity?

Comment: That's weird because invalidateOptionsMenu should be available inside a SherlockActivity derived class

Comment: Can you post your complete activity (or at least a not working sample)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your _ WebAppInterface_ class already has a Context member. Make it a SherlockActivity (better if you change the name)

```
public class WebAppInterface {
     SherlockActivity mActivity;

WebAppInterface(SherlockActivity c) {
    mActivity = c;
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void makeupdateshowToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mainMenu.findItem(R.id.refresh).setVisible(false);
    mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

}
```

and call

```
mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

Comment: I just copied the new WebAppInterface over the old one. I needed to do something else?

Comment: Its compiling, but the actionbar dont refresh. I need rotate the phone to refresh the actionbar (refresh on changing to landscape mode)